# How can I get in a "mouseover" event over a dataview table, in Wicket, the Row I'm over it with my mouse?

Tags: java, wicket, mouseover, dataview

I have in Wicket, an dataview and I would need, in a event like this:

```
itemContainer.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("mouseover") {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        IRequestParameters parameters = getRequest().getRequestParameters();
    }
});
```

To know which row in the column I put the mouse over.
The debug is entering here when hoovering the mouse over the desired column but I only get in parameters `parameters.getParameterValue("returnTabIndex")` but this returns the column and I would need the row I'm over it.
Does anyone knows how can I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Hi,
which component are you referring to? It's not clear to me what resultTable is...

Comment: sorry, it was an internal component, it's about a dataview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if itemContainer is of type  org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.Item (or LoopItem) it should expose method getIndex which should return the row number it represents.